# Replace one image with another using hover

Tags: html, css, hover, pseudo-class

I have this code

```
<div class="mix category-1">

<a href="img/holder-01-large.png" class="photo">

<img src="img/holder-01-small.png alt="Ram - Srbija" class="img-small-1"></a>

<a href="img/slider-photo-1.jpg" target="_blank" class="techdraw">Primer montaze</a>

<a class="popup-youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dz1kDQEHJaU">Video primer</a>

</div>
```

I want to replace this holder-01-small.png when hover over it with image with same dimensions. Is that possible by not touching this HTML code, just using CSS?

Comment: You'll have to change the HTML anyway, because you must insert a `"` at the end of the src.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possibly using this HTML, yes. (As long as you insert the missing quote after the src, that is!)

```css
a.photo:hover img {
  display: none
}
a.photo:hover::after {
  content: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100);
}
```

```html
<div class="mix category-1">

  <a href="img/holder-01-large.png" class="photo">

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/100/100" alt="Ram - Srbija" class="img-small-1" />

  </a>

  <a href="img/slider-photo-1.jpg" target="_blank" class="techdraw">Primer montaze</a>

  <a class="popup-youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dz1kDQEHJaU">Video primer</a>

</div>
```

Note that I changed the HTML to point to another image on the web in order to show something here in the snippet; hope you don't consider that to be cheating!

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Just one more question. Image holder-01-small.png have margin-bottom:7px; I want to set that value to the new picture when hovered. How?

Comment: That's a bit difficult. Would it help to give the `<a>` a 7px padding-bottom instead?

Comment: Under the image i have two buttons. I gave them 7px margin-top. Can i do that? Maybe it's not such a good idea but everything seems good now, like i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, but not using the approach you have presented.
Instead, create a div (using an img tag here would mean we would need a transparent image to act as a placeholder, whereas a div will just work)

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

And in css try something like the below, you will need to specify a height and a width as the div will technically be empty, otherwise it will just collapse on itself.

```
.image {
    background-image: url("path-to-file");
    height: xx;
    width: yy;
}

.image:hover {
    background-image: url("path-to-different-file");
}
```

This div will then change it's background image.

Comment: Thanks for help! Mr Lister solution worked best for me.

Comment: Sorry, i need to ask you how to make a link from that .image class? I need that image to be clickable to open a larger image.

Answer (score 0):

if you can place a `div` instead of an `img`tag, you can add the `background-img`property in css and then a hover. Something like this:

```
.img-small-1{
  background-img: url('..img/holder-01-small.png');
  width: 'your image's width';
  height: 'your image's height';
}

.img-small-1:hover {
  background-img: url('..img/myOtherImage.png');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help! Mr Lister solution worked best for me.